# gvim regex search and increment number

Tags: regex, vim

i have a txt file with alot of lines :

```
output [15:0] reg1;
input [16:0] reg2;
output [17:0] reg3;
etc...
```

and i want to change it to :

```
output 16 reg1;
input 17 reg2;
output 18 reg3;
```

i tried to implement it with regex, however it doesn't work for me..

```
:s/\(output\|input\)\s\+\[\d\+:0\]\(.*\)/\1 \=submatch(0)+1) \2/
```

hope someone can help me?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
:%s/\v\[(\d+):0\]/\=submatch(1)+1/g

/*
    %s              all lines search and replace
    \v              very magic regex, no extra '\'
    \[(\d+):0\]     Match string, default capture group ID = 0
    (\d+)           capture group ID = 1
    \=submatch(1)+1 returns submatch and calc, replace matches with results
    /g              replace all occurrences in the line

    :%s/{pattern}/{string}/[flags]
*/
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.

Comment: @IdanRahamim You can enter the command ':help \v' in vim to see the details about very magic mode.